# how to read existing jdb file java berkeley db

Tags: java, berkeley-db-je

I am trying to read a generated database (*.jdb) file.

For creating a new database I use:

```
    storeConfig_ = new StoreConfig();
    storeConfig_.setAllowCreate(true);
```

What StoreConfig parameters must I pass in to read an already existing *.jdb file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Configure the environment.
2. Create environment defining it's location.
3. Create new EntityStore using the predefined DAO.
4. Then you can access the database using the index.

   ```
   EnvironmentConfig envConfig = new EnvironmentConfig();

   try {
       myDbEnvironment_ = new Environment(new File(getDatabasePathString()), envConfig);
   } catch (DatabaseException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   DAO.store_ = new EntityStore(environment, "EntityStore", new StoreConfig());
   Index_ = store_.getPrimaryIndex(String.class, Page.class);
   ```